# RichTextBox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want set a line of text link in rich text box of vb.net. Like for example: I want to know you

The word want, I want to set a link word.

Can I do that?

Comment: there are so many free editors are there just check one of those

fckeditor google it

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it.

```
Dim linkLa As New LinkLabel
linkLa.LinkColor = Color.Red

Dim link As LinkLabel.Link = linkLa.Links.Add(0, 13, "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
linkLa.Text = "Stackoverflow"
AddHandler linkLa.LinkClicked, AddressOf Link_Clicked

richTextBox1.Controls.Add(linkLa)

Private Sub Link_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("clicked")
End Sub
```

Comment: you could simply just set richTextBox1.DetectUrls = true and then just enter your address as plain text. Or change linkLa.Text to the address instead of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for you. This will allow you to show the link target address as a tooltip. (little pop up bubble.) Other than that, it's similar to Stan R.'s answer.

1. Put this code under the "add link" button (or whatever you're calling it) in your program

Note: I put comments before each line, so it's easier to follow!

---

```
'define the text and link targets
Dim linktext As String = LinkTextbox.Text 'LinkTextbox is just the textbox where the user inputs the text of the link
Dim linktarget As String = LinkTargetTextbox.Text 'LinkTargetTextBox is just the textbox where the user inputs the target URL of the link

'Define the LinkLabel
Dim lnk As New LinkLabel
'if you want, you can set the different properties, like font or linkcolor, programmatically after defining the linklabel, for instance:
lnk.LinkColor = Color.Blue
'set tooltip
lnk.Tooltip = linktarget
'set the link target
Dim lk As LinkLabel.Link = lnk.Links.Add(0, 13, linktarget)
'set the link text
lnk.Text = linktext
'EventHandler
AddHandler lnk.LinkClicked, AddressOf LinkClicked
'Add the control to the richtextbox
RichTextBox1.Controls.Add(lnk)
'This is the Subroutine that the label will run when clicked (Make sure to put your "End Sub" before this, because it's not part of the button's subroutine)
Private Sub LinkClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'send link to the browser
    Process.Start(linktarget)
End Sub
```